# Why can't I install PSReadLine

Tags: powershell, installation, module

I am trying to install the *PSReadLine* module:

```
PS> Find-Module PSReadLine | Install-Module -scope currentUser -force
```

This command runs and terminates without any message or any indication that something was unsuccessful.

However, when I want to load the module, I get an error message:

```
PS> import-module PSReadLine

import-module : The specified module 'PSReadLine' was not loaded
because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
```

So, I am wondering how I can install and/or load this module.

### Feedback on comments

As per @Lee_Dailey's comment, I do indeed have a path with a lowercase `l`:

```
PS> ls 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\psread*' -name
PSReadline
```

Unfortunately, I cannot change that lowercase `l` to a `L` because I have this issue on a machine without admin privileges.

As per @Scepticalist comment, I should find the module in one of the module paths' locations. It turns out: I don't. The following command returns/prints nothing:

```
foreach ($mp in $Env:PSModulePath -split ';') { ls "$mp\psread*" }
```

Thus, also the command suggested by @pwnosh returns nothing:

```
($env:PSModulePath -split ';' | Get-ChildItem -Filter 'PSReadLine' | Get-ChildItem).FullName
```

`Find-Module PSReadLine` returns (echoes)

```
Version    Name            Repository    Description
-------    ----            ----------    -----------
2.1.0      PSReadLine      PSGallery     Great command line editing in the PowerShell console host
```

Running `Register-PSRepository -Default` results in an error message:

```
PackageManagement\Register-PackageSource : Module Repository 'PSGallery' exists.
```

`Set-PSRepository 'PSGallery' -InstallationPolicy Trusted` runs and terminates without any message echoed to the console. Yet, after running this command, I am still unable to import the module.

Comment: take a look at this article ... Updating help for the PSReadLine module | PowerShell Team — https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/updating-help-for-the-psreadline-module/ ... it appears to be a nasty case-sensitivity glitch that must be fixed manually. **_that same glitch may apply to your situation._**

Comment: After the module is installed, there should be a folder by the same name in the module location for your user profile, which can be found from the $Env:PSModulePath variable. Go check if it's actually present

Comment: Maybe the "latest" module of PSReadLine used by PowerShell is corrupt . Can you please provide the response for: `($env:PSModulePath -split ';' | Get-ChildItem -Filter 'PSReadLine' | Get-ChildItem).FullName`. PS: This shows the the order of the module loading in terms of directories. The highest version per directory wins.

Comment: Does just `Find-Module PSReadLine` return something? Try also `Register-PSRepository -Default` to register PowerShell Gallery as repository and `Set-PSRepository 'PSGallery' -InstallationPolicy Trusted` to trust that Gallery.